# ERROR, vertex_descriptor': is not a member of 'StitchPolyhedron', if StitchPolyhedron is inherited from Polyhedron_3

Tags: cgal

There is an error if class inherits from Polyhedron_3 and used in stitch_borders, but if I use the Polyhedron_3 directly in stitch_borders there is no error.

```
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
class StitchPolyhedron : public CGAL::Polyhedron_3<K>
{
public:
    StitchPolyhedron() {}
    virtual ~StitchPolyhedron() {}
};

StitchPolyhedron mesh;
CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::stitch_borders(mesh);
```

Code above gives an error

> vertex_descriptor': is not a member of 'StitchPolyhedron'

```
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_3<K> StitchPolyhedron;

StitchPolyhedron mesh;
CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::stitch_borders(mesh);
```

Code above compiles fine.

Can anyone point me what is the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Your inherited class must be a model of `FaceListGraph`. Usually adding in a `boost` namespace the following partial specialization should be sufficient:

```
namespace boost {
struct boost::graph_traits<POLYHEDRON_TYPE>:
  public boost::graph_traits<BASE_POLYHEDRON_TYPE>
{};
} // namespace boost
```

You might need to forward properties as well. Add in a `boost` namespace the following partial specialization:

```
namespace boost{
template <class Tag>
struct property_map<POLYHEDRON_TYPE, Tag> :
  public property_map<BASE_POLYHEDRON_TYPE, Tag>
{};
} //namespace boost
```